# @RestController very slow with @ManyToMany

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is it normal if you are using a Spring MVC Controller annotated with `@RestController` on Spring Data JPA entities with `@ManyToMany` to run very very slow?

Each of the entities are annotated with `@JsonManagedReference` for the parent and `@JsonBackReference` for the children.

I seeded the database with 300 records and 3 to 4 of the children are populated only for record 1 of the parent entity.

Is Paging the only real answer to limit the query size to help with the speed?

Comment: There's basically no connection between the two whatsoever. It would be helpful to provide more details on what you're doing, a test case to reproduce the behavior etc.

Comment: I ended up replacing this implementation with SDR. (Models the same) This did solve the problem. Some experimenting, I found that adding @JsonIgnore to the relationships took load time from 8s to 400ms